# negative look ahead producing unexpected result

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I was expecting an empty string, because I'm specifically negating the word
'authentication' which is within my string.

```
string ='INFO 2013-09-17 12:13:44,487 authentication failed'

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+\s[\d-]+\s[\d:,]+\s(.*(?!authentication\s)failed)')

re.findall(pattern, string)
['authentication failed']
```

Can someone explain why this is failing?

Comment: Use a lookbehind - [`pattern = re.compile(r'\w+\s[\d-]+\s[\d:,]+\s(.*(?<!authentication\s)failed)')`](https://ideone.com/xtGtSM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.*` pattern matches anything before `failed`. That *anything* itself should not be followed by `authentication` plus 1 whitespace character. That restriction is met easily; there is no `authentication` with whitespace right after `'authentication '`.

Invert the lookahead; use a negative lookbehind (`(?<!...)`) instead. Only match `failed` if it is not directly preceded by `authentication`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+\s[\d-]+\s[\d:,]+\s(.*(?<!authentication\s)failed)')
```

Now the text doesn't match; the `.*` can't match anything as there is no valid `failed` text following it that is not also preceded by `authentication`.

I've put a demo at https://regex101.com/r/yGW7rH/1; note that the second line with the text `matching failed` results in a match, while `authentication failed` does not.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I was confused as to look behind works and not look ahead - but you clarified those points succinctly. I will accept your answer after the time-limit suspends.